# Grab data from a query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to learn PHP, and to do so I'm attempting to create a URL shortener. Right now you can currently input a link and it enters it into the database. It doesn't randomize the string, but I'm going to do that after. (I changed them myself to avoid running into problems).

Here is my table currently(My table is called 'urls'):

[image: Table]

Then when you go to (for me localhost) /somepath it automatically redirects to /process.php?id=somepath

In process.php it checks if the specified path (somepath) exists in the database, then gets its original value. The problem I'm having is getting the original value. Again, I am new to PHP, and I'm having trouble understanding how querying works.

```
$query = "SELECT original FROM urls WHERE new = '$new'";
$result = $conn->query($query);
```

How do I grab information from $result? Or am I supposed to get it from $query after $result because that just basically runs it?

Please explain why you use what, I'm not understanding this.

Thanks, sorry if this is a really stupid question.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `fetch_assoc()` to grab data from your table in MySQLi Object-oriented.

Try this:

```
$query = "SELECT original FROM urls WHERE new = '$new'";
$result = $conn->query($query);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
}
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

You can also put the result in an HTML table:

```
 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr>";
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["firstname"]." ".$row["lastname"]."</td></tr>";
     }
     echo "</table>";
 } else {
     echo "0 results";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In this code, I used the `object oriented approach` for a `prepared statement` or if you are still into `procedural style`, you can still use that.

Check this link: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

So basically, what happens in this code is that the query is being prepared then you bind the parameter to be used (this style is one way to avoid SQL injections because inputs are automatically escaped). The result will be first stored in the variable `$original` then I counted how many rows the query returned. If it is more than 1, it means there is a match, then if 0, no match.

If there is a match, it will echo the value of the variable `$original`.

```
<?php

  $stmt = $conn -> prepare("SELECT original FROM urls WHERE new = ?");
  $stmt -> bind_param('s',$new);
  $stmt -> execute();
  $stmt -> bind_result($original);
  $stmt -> fetch();
  $stmt -> store_result();

  $res = $stmt -> num_rows();

  $stmt -> close();

  if($res > 0){
    echo $original;
  }
  else{
    //not found
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT original FROM urls WHERE new = '$new'";
$result = $conn->query($query);    
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($result);
foreach($rows as $row){

     echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
}
```

You can use either `mysql_fetch_array` or `mysql_fetch_assoc` for grab results